# Why do COM port numbers between Arduino and Processing not match?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication, processing-lang

I have a Processing program that reads data sent to the serial port by an Arduino. When I go to device manager it shows that the Arduino is plugged into COM 4, however in order to get Processing to read the data the number I need for the COM in the following line is 2:

```
String portName = Serial.list()[2]
```

Why do the numbers not match?

Thanks!

Comment: what numbers are you talking about?

Comment: `Serial.list()[2]` can easily refer to COM4 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print out portName it should be **COM4** it seems you must have 3 COM ports on your machine otherwise you would use index 0; Serial.List() appears to return an array or list which you are taking the third item located at index 2.

Comment: Indeed. The numbers *do* match. But *you* are trying to match a *number* with a *name*, and those do *not* match. Or are you Number 6?